# create view mysql error

Tags: mysql

```
create view 'V_Compras' as
select *
from h_cotizacion 
inner join cotizacion on h_cotizacion.id_cotizacion =  
cotizacion.id_cotizacion
inner join productos on h_cotizacion.id_producto = productos.id_productos 
inner join cliente on h_cotizacion.id_cliente = cliente.id_cliente;
```

Aparece Error Code:

> 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>         near ''V_Compras' as select * from h_cotizacion hc inner join
>         cotizacion c on hc.id_co' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenes un error en las comillas que usaste para el nombre.
Probá asi:

```
create view `V_Compras` as 
select * 
from 
    h_cotizacion 
inner join 
    cotizacion on h_cotizacion.id_cotizacion = cotizacion.id_cotizacion 
inner join 
    productos on h_cotizacion.id_producto = productos.id_productos 
inner join 
    cliente on h_cotizacion.id_cliente = cliente.id_cliente;
```

Comment: Hola Jose, me aparece Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'id_cotizacion'

Comment: @thelaw probablemente el campo id_cotizacion esté más de una vez en las tablas. Modificá el select para seleccionar los campos que necesitas de la vista. Por ejemplo: select h_cotizacion.id, h_cotizacion.fecha etc. No te puedo ayudar mas porque no se que campos hay en cada tabla. Si queres actualiza la consulta con esos datos para poder revisarla.

Comment: y no se puede llamar con un select * ?

Comment: no, si los nombres de los campos devueltos por la consulta se repiten. también podes cambiarles el nombre, pero para eso también tenes que enumerarlos. Por ejemplo: select h_cotizacion.id_cotizacion as id1, cotizacion.id_cotizacion as id2

Answer (score 0):

Aqui un ejemplo de como deberias crear tu vista usa la siguiente sintaxis:

```
 CREATE VIEW 
 vista_futbolistas AS 
 SELECT futbolistas.id, nombre, apellidos FROM futbolistas
 INNER JOIN tarjetas_amarillas 
 ON futbolistas.id = tarjetas_amarillas.id_futbolista;
```

EN tu caso seria:

```
create view 
V_Compras AS
select *
from h_cotizacion 
inner join cotizacion on h_cotizacion.id_cotizacion =  
cotizacion.id_cotizacion
inner join productos on h_cotizacion.id_producto = productos.id_productos 
inner join cliente on h_cotizacion.id_cliente = cliente.id_cliente;
```

Si te das cuenta le saque las comillas al V_compras.

Comment: tengo una duda, si tengo bien mi consulta por que me da el error en el id duplicado ?

Comment: Por que en tu select estas llamando  `Selet *` , y puede que existan dos columnas con el mismo id.

Comment: En el select utiliza los datos que realmente necesitas, es decir `Select h_cotizacion.id_cotizacion.`  Si te das cuenta el `id_cotizacion` lo tienes en la tabla `cotizacion` y en la tabla `h_cotizacion` tienes que llamar a uno de esos en el select. ya que te obliga a tener solo uno.